# Spring AOP proxied session bean retains after session timeout and dies only after container restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have a AOP proxied session scoped bean in Spring Controller which does not die after closing the browser or even after the session timeout of 30 minutes configured in `web.xml`. Is it possible to destroy the bean when browser is closed or after session timeout? I'm using Spring 3.2.2 modules on Tomcat 7 server

**Update:** After using the session listener, this is what I've found.

1. Opened a browser with the app url, a session is created. Then I bind some inputs with some test values.
2. Then I close the browser and container still has the session in step 1 because closing browser only wipes the JSESSIONID
3. Now I open the browser with the same app url, another session is created but it uses the same bean with the same values that I bound in step 1.
4. Again I repeat steps 2 and 3 over and over and 'n' number of sessions get created.
5. I wait for 30 minutes and all of the n sessions are destroyed.
6. Now I open browser again and the session is created with the same old values that I have bound in step 1.

So the bound values are lost only after restarting the server. Why aren't the beans destroyed when the 'n' sessions are destroyed??

**SSCCE:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MyAppController {

// AOP session scoped proxy type CGLIB
@Autowired  private InputForm inputForm;

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView returnHome() {
    Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modelMap.put("inputForm", inputForm);
    return new ModelAndView("homePage", modelMap); 
}
}


public class InputForm {

private String id;
private String name;
private String phoneNo;
private List<Person> personKeys = new AutoPopulatingList<Person>(Person.class);

public void init() {
    this.getPersonKeys().add(new Person(this.id, this.name, this.phoneNo));
}

// getters and setters
```

}

```
<bean id="inputForm" class="<package>.InputForm" 
                        scope="session" init-method="init">
    <property name="id" value="${property_id}"/>
    <property name="name" value="${property_name}"/>
    <property name="phoneNo" value="${property_phone}"/>
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: is it getting injected beans that out-live the session by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I waited for session timeout which was set as 30 minutes and yet the bean is injected with the old values.

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no way<sup>1</sup> to detect a browser closing. The bean will die when the session times out and is invalidated.

<sup>1</sup><sub>(fail-safe)</sub>

Comment: As said in another comment, the bean doesn't die after session timeout

Comment: @User49234123412341 Please edit your question and show us how you are configuring and injecting the session scoped bean.

Comment: @User49234123412341 In the code you've shown, what you have injected is the proxy. When you call methods on it, if a session scoped object doesn't exist, one will be created and the method will be delegated to it. Here, it doesn't seem like you do call any methods on it, so no object gets created, so nothing gets removed from the session.

Comment: @User49234123412341 Can you clarify what you mean by `Now I open the browser with the same app url, another session is created but it uses the same bean with the same values that I bound in step 1.`? In the code you've shown, you don't use the `InputForm` bean except putting into model attributes, but that doesn't actually trigger the underlying bean. You also don't show any code that changes the value of `InputForm` so how do you check if it's different or not?

Comment: @User49234123412341 Try logging the values and changing them. Use a static incrementing counter or something to differentiate between objects/sessions.

Comment: It doesn't matter how and where I'm binding those values, I'm still getting the old bean, instead it should be the bean with the values set in the init method right? Its obviously session scoped but it doesn't die even after session timeout, it only dies after restarting server. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Ah! Interesting, you seem to have posted a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533038/session-scoped-bean-as-class-attribute-of-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: @User49234123412341 You seem to be creating all the beans with the same values, how do you distinguish between them? I don't understand where you are seeing them as the same bean across sessions.

Comment: @User49234123412341 As a test, you can add a `destroy-method` and see if it is called. Don't wait 30 minutes though, set it to like 1 minute or less.

Comment: I haven't tested this across sessions yet. But I just wanted the bean to die after session timeout as you have said  in the answer but it doesn't. Anyway I will add the destroy-method like you said and see how it goes.

Comment: But I understood the way it works that as long as we call any set methods the bean should change the way it is. So in that case, I can add a clean up method in my session listener to clear the bean after timeout

Comment: @User49234123412341 Right. The object that is injected into `@Autowired` field is a **proxy**. It delegates to an actual instance when you invoke a method on it. That instance is stored in the `HttpSession` and removed when it times out.